# Destroy a full linked list (c programming)

Tags: c

I am a beginner to C programming and am  a bit stuck on pointers. i am trying to create a function that deletes all the elements of the linkes list. However my code deletes all elements except for the head.

I cannot alter the

> void destroy(node *h)

parameters due to assignment title.

```
void destroy(set_element* head){
    set_element* temp ;
    set_element* curr = head;

    if(head){
        curr = head->next;
        head->next = NULL;

        while(curr !=NULL){
            temp = curr->next;
            free(curr);
            curr = temp;
        }
        head =NULL;
    }
}
```

thanks in advance.

Comment: Please don't learn C from the gutter. Read Kernighan and Ritchie.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is this line

```
curr = head->next;
```

Here you make `curr` point to the *next* node. You need to make `curr` point directly to `head`.

A simpler version of the function might be e.g. this:

```
void destroy(set_element **head)
{
    set_element *next;
    for (set_element *curr = *head; curr; curr = next)
    {
        next = curr->next;
        free(curr);
    }

    *head = NULL;
}
```

Note that I pass the `head` pointer *by reference*, otherwise the assignment to `NULL` will only change the local copy of the pointer.

Comment: Is there any way to edit my code without changing the >void destroy(set element * head) ? 
This was given to me in the assignment and i cannot change it. 
thanks .

Comment: @tas My function will work with that to (but use `head` instead of `*head`) with the only exception that you can't set `head` to `NULL`.

Answer (score 1):

If all you want to do is delete the entire linked list (head node included) and don't care whether the caller is left with a dangling pointer, this gets significantly simpler:

```
void destroy(set_element* head)
{
    set_element* temp;
    while (head)
    {
        temp = head;
        head = head->next;
        free(temp);
    }
}
```

Invoked on the caller side as:

```
destroy(head);
```

That said, if you want to modify the *callers* passed-in pointer you cannot do it with this function signature. Like all other things in C (arrays not withstanding) parameters are passed by value, and if you need to modify the callers data, the parameter must be a pointer, and the passed-in value an address:

```
void destroy(set_element** headp)
{
    set_element* temp;
    while (*headp)
    {
        temp = *headp;
        *headp = temp->next;
        free(temp);
    }
}
```

Invoked on the caller side as

```
destroy(&head);
```

Both of these assume your list is properly terminated with NULL.